# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_n) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X) < \infty$, and let $f \in L^1(X)$, be such that $|f(x)| > 0$ a.e. Let $A_n \in \mathcal{M}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{A_n}|f|d\mu = 0$$

Now, I would like to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_n) = 0$. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Consider the measure $\nu= f\,d\mu$. Notice that $d\mu = \frac{1}{f}\,d\nu$ ($\frac{1}{f}$ is well define since $f>0$) Then $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent, that is $\mu\ll \nu$ and $\mu\ll \nu$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Write $X=\bigcup_m B_m$, where $B_m=\{x\in X\mid \lvert f(x)\rvert\geq 1/m\}$ and observe that $\lim_{m\to \infty}\mu(X\setminus B_m)= 0$ and for each $m$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mu(A_n\cap B_m)=0$. Finish by noticing that $$\mu(A_n)\leq\mu(A_n\cap B_m)+\mu(X\setminus B_m).$$

(By the way, if $\mu(X)$ is infinite, then $\lim_{m\to \infty}\mu(X\setminus B_m)=0$ might fail, which is why you can have examples like $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, $A_n=(n,n+1)$.)

Comment: Could you clarify why $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n \cap B_m) = 0$?

Comment: @akai: Because $\int_{A_n} \lvert f\rvert \, \mathrm{d}\mu\geq \mu(A_n\cap B_m)/m$.